# What is the difference between abstraction and interface?

Tags: c++

I found the following definitions from the internet and both sound similar to me :

Abstraction : Abstraction is another good feature of OOPS. Abstraction means to show only the necessary details to the client of the object. Do you know the inner details of the Monitor of your PC? What happen when you switch ON Monitor? Does this matter to you what is happening inside the Monitor? No Right, Important thing for you is weather Monitor is ON or NOT. When you change the gear of your vehicle are you really concern about the inner details of your vehicle engine? No but what matter to you is that Gear must get changed that’s it!! This is abstraction; show only the details which matter to the user. 
Let’s say you have a method "CalculateSalary" in your Employee class, which takes EmployeeId as parameter and returns the salary of the employee for the current month as an integer value. Now if someone wants to use that method. He does not need to care about how Employee object calculates the salary? An only thing he needs to be concern is name of the method, its input parameters and format of resulting member, Right? 
So abstraction says expose only the details which are concern with the user (client) of your object. So the client who is using your class need not to be aware of the inner details like how you class do the operations? He needs to know just few details. This certainly helps in reusability of the code.

Interface : An interface is a description of the actions that an object can do... for example when you flip a light switch, the light goes on, you don't care how, just that it does. In Object Oriented Programming, an Interface is a description of all functions that an object must have in order to be an "X". Again, as an example, anything that "ACTS LIKE" a light, should have a turn_on() method and a turn_off() method. The purpose of interfaces is to allow the computer to enforce these properties and to know that an object of TYPE T (whatever the interface is ) must have functions called X,Y,Z, etc.

Interfaces in Object Oriented Programming Languages

An interface is a programming structure/syntax that allows the computer to enforce certain properties on an object (class). For example, say we have a car class and a scooter class and a truck class. Each of these three classes should have a start_engine() action. How the "engine is started" for each vehicle is left to each particular class, but the fact that they must have a start_engine action is the domain of the interface.

Doesn't both the explanations say the same thing? So are they same or different?

Comment: I understand "abstraction" is more general word (more abstract btw), 1. theoretical way OOP thinking about problem. 2 software canon/pattern. Word "interface" is more specialistic, belong to writing code (programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface tells you *what* you can do with something. Abstract(ion) *might* additionally tell you *how* you do some of these. Thus an interface is always a kind of abstraction, but an abstraction can carry more information than an interface.

In C++-world, unlike e.g. Java, there's no explicit declaration of an interface; instead, your class automatically provides all the interfaces that the base classes provide. Some of us tend to call classes with only pure virtual methods (and, possibly, a non-pure virtual destructor) and interface. Note that, strictly speaking, it's not the only way do specify an interface and new/upcoming C++ features (like Concepts) will likely change this scene. Similarly we usually say that a class is abstract when it has at least one pure virtual method, albeit there might be different definitions when you use template/traits based composition and fulfilling and interface instead of virtuals and inheritance for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Abstraction is to move away from the details, to 'zoom out', if you will. You tend to abstract away from the implementation by creating structures to lay out your code. As an example, rather than thinking in terms of individual cells in a body, you could abstract away to thinking about the person as a whole, or go even further and think about groups of people.

An interface is just that; how you interface with your code. This is normally in the form of `public` functions in your classes, though not necessarily. Ideally, the interface should describe what something can do, without being affected by how it does it. For example, you might have a function to get a person to walk, but not one to move their individual muscles.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of , say, a C++ function:

The ***interface*** describes how a feature is used which is what a function prototype does.

A client calling the function need not worry how the function is implemented (ie how it go about doing things). In short you have a layer of ***abstraction***.